# Python - Task exception was never retrieved & AttributeError: __aexit__

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
start = time.time()
urls = [
    'http://127.0.0.1:5000/W',
    'http://127.0.0.1:5000/P',
    'http://127.0.0.1:5000/X'
]

tasks = []

async def get_page(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession as session:
        async with await session.get(url) as response:
            page_text = await response.text()
            print(page_text)

for url in urls:
    a_response = get_page(url)
    task = asyncio.ensure_future(a_response)
    tasks.append(task)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))

end = time.time()
print('Time：',end-start)
```

And below is my Flask:

```
from flask import Flask
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/W')
def index_W():
    time.sleep(2)
    return "Hello W"

@app.route('/P')
def index_P():
    time.sleep(2)
    return "Hello P"

@app.route('/X')
def index_X():
    time.sleep(2)
    return "Hello X"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(threaded = True)
```

Mainly, the error is"Task exception was never retrieved" and "AtrributeError:**aexit**"

Here is the details:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-3' coro=<get_page() done, defined at C:/Users/PeterWu/IdeaProjects/untitled/crawler.py:346> exception=AttributeError('__aexit__')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PeterWu/IdeaProjects/untitled/crawler.py", line 347, in get_page
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession as session:
AttributeError: __aexit__
```

Maybe I should add the try-catch block? It seems that I don't have any grammar mistake

Comment: OK,I get it
I'm such a fool..

Comment: If you have found a solution, please answer your own question and share your solution with the community.

Comment: Sure 
my code was```async with aiohttp.ClientSession as session:```
and it suppose to be ```async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:```